# Sencha List shows no data

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a ProfileView which should show some user data. This is the first time I am trying to get data from MySql and showing it on a Sencha view.

**The view**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Profile', {
extend : 'Ext.Panel',
xtype : 'profileview',

requires : ['Ext.List', 'Ext.data.Store'],

config : {
    layout: 'fit',
    title : 'Profiel',
    iconCls : 'user3',
    cls : 'home',
    scrollable : true,
    styleHtmlContent : true,
    html : ['<h1>Mijn Profiel</h1>'].join(""),
    items : [Ext.create('Ext.List', {
        title : 'Profile',
        docked : 'top',
        store : myStore,
        show : function(list, opts) {
            alert('list === ' + list);
            console.log('List Shown: ' + list);
        }
    })]
}
```

});

```
var myStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
model : "MyApp.model.User",
proxy : {
    type : "ajax",
    url : "php/get_user.php",
    reader : {
        type : "json"
        // rootProperty : "users"
    }
},
autoLoad : true
});
```

The data is returned correctly but nothing is shown, and this I am trying to figure out.

**The Response**

```
[{"ID":"19","USERNAME":"Annet","EMAIL":"annet@annet.nl"}]
```

I skipped the rootProperty because it is a single user.

**The Model**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
config : {
    fields : [{
        name : 'ID',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'USERNAME',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'EMAIL',
        type : 'string'
    }]
}
```

});

So, why does the list not show anything ?

**Update**

I check to see it the store contains data and it does

```
map: Object
ext-record-1: Class
_data: Object
EMAIL: "annet@annet.nl"
ID: 19
USERNAME: "Annet"
id: "ext-record-1"
__proto__: Object
```

Why is it not picked up by the list? I tried DataView as well.

Comment: try to log store in console. so that we can find out is it the data that is not coming in the store or is it the list which is not showing the data. also to check put ome dummy data in the store first and if it displays the data then see we can figur if the data from php is giving us trouble

Comment: @SirwaniMayur the store contains data, see my update.

Comment: but the following line is not executed : console.log('List Shown: ' + list);

Comment: aarghhhh, its a sequence thing, the Store was created below the define of the View, my basis ExtJS knowledge lacked there....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [itemTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-itemTpl), i changed code for you.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Profile', {
extend : 'Ext.Panel',
xtype : 'profileview',

requires : ['Ext.List', 'Ext.data.Store'],

config : {
    layout: 'fit',
    title : 'Profiel',
    iconCls : 'user3',
    cls : 'home',
    scrollable : true,
    styleHtmlContent : true,
    html : ['<h1>Mijn Profiel</h1>'].join(""),
    items : [Ext.create('Ext.List', {
        title : 'Profile',
        docked : 'top',
        itemTpl : '<div>{ID} <span> {USERNAME} </span> <span> {EMAIL} </span> </div>',
        store : myStore,
        show : function(list, opts) {
            alert('list === ' + list);
            console.log('List Shown: ' + list);
        }
    })]
}
});
```